# Application's Datapath - os.environ

Tags: python

I am developing a Python Desktop application and I have been able to get it to work just fine, I am just having trouble getting classes to locate the database.

This application was build on the Windows platform and used the following code to create the database.

```
appDataPath = os.environ["APPDATA"] + "\\FolderName\\"
```

However, in mac, there is no APPDATA and I have been using HOME instead, but it creates the files on build as FolderNameapplication.db which is a real hassle.

The database is now residing on the Desktop (HOME) after removing the `"\FolderName\" extension and I need the appDataPath variable to point at the database. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I think some of these questions are related & might give an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=appdata+osx+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks for your help! However, they don't address grabbing the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.join()` to construct paths. OS X (and Linux) don't use backslashes for paths like Windows does so adding those strings with hard-coded path separators will cause you problems. (Although forward slashes can work on Windows...)

Example: `os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'somedir', 'mydb.db')`

The usual OS X alternative to appdata is `~/Library/Application Support/appname/`